# Fluid width not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, width

Good evening, very new to the web design world but loving it so far, and this site has helped me so much but I'm stuck with a firefox problem.

In Safari, IE, Chrome and Opera my layout works as it is supposed to. But in Firefox alone, the min-width property is not working! The layout keeps compressing and the 15px right margin keeps moving to the left instead of stopping (like it does in the 4 other browsers!)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IL_new.css">
        <title>Name here</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
<div id="header-text">Name here</div>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
<div id="margin">
<div id="shell">

</div>
</div>


</body></html>
```

with styling:

```
header {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,       #19cad5 0%,#0066b5 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,       #19cad5 0%,#0066b5 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #19cad5 0%,#0066b5 100%); 
border: solid black; border-width: 1 0 1 0;
height: 125px;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
position: relative;
min-width: 900;
}



#header-text {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: #610079  ;
    height: 125;
    position: absolute; left:0px; bottom:0px;
    padding:0 0 0 30;
    font-family: "verdana"; font-size: 48px; font-weight: bold;
}



/* START DROP DOWN NAV MENU */

nav {
    position:absolute; right:0px; bottom:0px; 
    padding:0 30 0 0;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15;
    list-style: none;
}

/* END DROP DOWN NAV MENU */

/* END HEADER */

/* START CONTAINERS */

#margin {
border: 1px solid red;
height: 300;
margin: 10 15;
min-width: 870;
}

#shell {
border: 1px solid green;
height: 300;
min-width: 870;
}


/* END CONTAINERS */
```

Being so new to this, I have no doubt there's some errors/back practices in my mark up BUT as mentioned, it is working exactly how I want it to in Opera, Safari, IE and Chrome but NOT FIREFOX!

*borders etc. are there for my design reference*

*i am using the latest versions of all browsers*

Thank you very much for your time.
Shane

Comment: you need to add a measure to your widths, min-widths, padding, border etc - eg px, em, %

Comment: Thank you Pete. I incorrectly assumed that because I could write "margin: 0 auto;" that i could leave off px from everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "px" at the end of your width, padding, height declarations

Comment: Thank you. I incorrectly assumed that because I could write "margin: 0 auto;" that i could leave off px from everything.

Comment: Thats a keen assumption.Only zero(number) css declarations can just have a null or 0 without a suffix attached to it's value. Anything else needs a px, em, cm, rem, etc attached to it to correctly tell the browser in which unit of measurement it should parse as. And as a side note. Do not worry, we were all beginners once. Keep kicking butt and trying!

Answer (score 1):

Run your html through a validator, fix the errors, and then take a look at it.

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thank you httpgio. Main problem was i did not have doctype html. Is there anything else really obvious I'm stuffing up?

Comment: yes, take OZ Laurens advice, and use px in your size declarations. I think there is a CSS validator as well. but for an example: 
nav {
    position:absolute; right:0px; bottom:0px; 
    padding:0px 30px 0px 0px;
}

Comment: PS: u dont need to use px when its a 0 (i just did it for the example)

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to respond to such an idiot @httpgio! That's why i didn't notice my own error - cause margin: 0 auto; always seemed to work.

Comment: Your not an idiot, your just learning. I sucked at CSS when I started too! But back in my day we had no stack overflow. I had to learn from trial and error! So just keep it up and you will learn in no time. (can u please accept my answer)